# Delete lines of a text file in R

Tags: r, readlines

I have a .xml file that I read with readLines() in R. 
I would like to know if there is some function that allow me to delete from line 15 to line 18.

I would need of a general command, because I have to repeat the function in loop on the same .xml file, but for the following lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`readLines` creates a character vector where each element is a line from the original file. If you want to remove lines 15 through 18, remove those elements from the vector.

```
my_new_file = current_file[-(15:18)]
```

You can then use `writeLines` to replace the old file with the edited version.

Comment: You can also use the `readr` package with the functions `read_lines` and `write_lines`.

Comment: @KerryJackson yes, probably several other packages too. While `readr` does have some clear feature advantages for delimited files and creating data frames/tibbles, I don't think `read_lines` offers any advantage over `readLines`...